# Data collected from ROS

Tags: ros, gyroscope, simulation, accelerometer, lidar

How can we collect the flight data after a ROS simulation and what kind of dataset do we obtain? Can we get the sensor and video dataset with timestamps to be used in analysis?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Jean, but I'm afraid that it is not clear what you are asking. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so it's a good idea to include details of what you want to achieve, what you tried, what you saw & what you expected to see. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works and work through the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) to edit your question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 3):

As Ben noticed, you may want to elaborate on your question, but in general data collection in ROS is performed using tools from the [rosbag](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag) package.

As you'll find when you read the documentation, data (either from a simulation or the real world) can be recorded *during* a session, but not after it has already finished.

Recorded data can be replayed or extracted for analysis on various ways. In particular I recommend you check the [API](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Code%20API) for programmatic manipulation of rosbag files, it includes many useful features, such as recovering message record times (which is very convenient for messages that don't already include a timestamp field).

Comment: Thank you Xperroni. I will try the rosbag package as soon as I can implement the sensors to my robot. All I want is to collect some data while the drone flies to be used for my data science thesis. Accelenometer, gyroscope, camera, sonar, lidar and radar datas can be useful.